# Pass files to S3 from EC2 instance

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, user-data

I am having AWS EC2 instance through which i am creating new AWS EC2 instances using command "ec2-run-instances".

This new instance is pre-configured with EC2 command line API and S3cmd API.

While creating instance i am passing user data to new instance in which i have written code for transferring file from that instance to AWS s3 bucket as follows.

```
 s3cmd put res.doc s3://BucketName/DocFiles/res.doc
```

but it not transfers res.doc to bucket.

After that i came to know that this script uploads that files which are exist on first EC2 instance from which i creates new instances.

So how can i solve this problem?

Script file is here:-

```
 str=$"#! /bin/bash"
 str+=$"\ncd /home"
 str+=$"\nmkdir pravin"
 str+=$"\ns3cmd put res.doc s3://BuckectName/DocFiles/res.csv"
 ud=`echo -e "$str" |base64`
 ec2-run-instances ami-784c2823 -t t1.micro -g group -n 1 -k key1 -d "$ud"
```

Comment: You may need to pass `--force` to `put` to tell it to overwrite the existing file.

Comment: @Lars : Sorry i not get it. While creating new instance it neither uploads file to s3 nor downloads file from s3 which is present on new instance.

But my code checks that files on first instance from which i am creating new instance.But it suppose to check on new instance.

Comment: Without showing us this code we can't possibly guess what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Lars :- Here i added script code in my question.

Comment: Did you check the logs on the VM for any errors?

Comment: @Lars :- It not shows any error but shows logs to uploaded file if file exist on first instance.
If file is not present then it show blank file.

But file is present on newly created instance.It checks on first instance.